# How to read the received text message information in twilio?

Tags: node.js, curl, sms, twilio, message

When I send a regular post request using curl `curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
     -d '{"name":"your name","phonenumber":"111-111"}' http://localhost:3000/theRoute`
 to my route that's supposed to receive text messages, i.e., the route set using `twilio phone-numbers:update "+11010101010" --sms-url="http://localhost:3000/theRoute"`, I can access the object sent through req.body.
However, when I send a text message to the phone number, i.e., +11010101010, I do receive the request, but `req.body` is empty. How do I access the text message information?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, are you using `body-parser`?

The body of the message that was sent to your Twilio number should be in `req.body.Body`.

---

Here is some code you could try for your server:

```js
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const { urlencoded } = require('body-parser');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;

const app = express();
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/theRoute', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  // console log the message body 
  console.log(`Message: ${req.body.Body}`);

  // respond  
  twiml.message('Thank you for your message!');

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
  res.end(twiml.toString());
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000');
});
```